# How to make controls "previous" and "next" move a scale widget slider?

Tags: tcl, scale, tk-toolkit

I am developing a user interface for a desktop player with controls of all standards. I would like to make a volume controller in the same style:

[image]

**Code simple, is my esbo:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec wish "$0" "$@"

. configure -width 100 -height 50

pack [button .btn1 -text "-" -command { bell }] -side left -fill none

pack [scale .scl0 -showvalue 1 -from 0 -to 10 -resolution 1 -orient horizontal] -side left -fill both

pack [button .btn2 -text "+" -command { bell }] -side right -fill none
```

That is all I have so far. I have no idea how to move the scale by pressing the buttons, making it go from left to right and right to left.

Comment: The answer also works with `ttk::button` and `ttk::scale`, which can be styled more deeply than the standard widgets. That can be useful for media players...

Comment: Also note that clicking in the slider trough to the right or left of the slider will increment and decrement the widget variable.

Comment: @BradLanam What variable are we talking about ??? Is this `-variable currentVolume` ?!

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Yes, the `-variable currentVolume`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to assign a variable to the scale, then a proc that modifies that variable. For example:

```
pack [button .btn1 -text "-" -command {volume -1}] -side left -fill none
pack [scale .scl0 -showvalue 1 -from 0 -to 10 -resolution 1 -orient horizontal \
    -variable currentVolume] -side left -fill both
pack [button .btn2 -text "+" -command {volume 1}] -side left -fill none

proc volume {val} {
    incr ::currentVolume $val
}
```